# Getting effective user Permissions for many directories

Tags: powershell, scripting

Usually `$Plist` would be an array but for example we take just one directory.

My problem is I can't use the `$ids` var. Somehow I cant read out the data and can't bypass it to:

```
Get-ADGroup -Identity $id -Properties member | Select-Object -ExpandProperty member
```

I need the usernames per directory with their group names.

Like : `Path GroupName UserList`

Can someone help? Maybe tweak my code or make something similar :)

```
$plist = "\\Server\Share"
$FList   = foreach($dir in $Plist)
{
    Resolve-Path -Path $dir
    Get-Acl -Path $dir -Filter Access | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Access | Where-Object {$_.IdentityReference -like "Domain\*"} | Select-Object IdentityReference
    Get-Item $dir | select FullName
}

$Flist | ft FullName, IdentityReference

$identity = $Flist.IdentityReference | out-string
$ids = foreach($ident in $identity)
{
    $ident = $ident.Replace("Domain\","")
    $ident    
}

foreach($id in $ids)
{
    $id
    Get-ADGroup -Identity $id -Properties member | Select-Object -ExpandProperty member
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do *not* use `ft` (`Format-Table`) or `Out-String` on values that you may ned later in your script.

```
$ids = foreach($ident in $Flist.IdentityReference){
    "$ident".Replace('Domain\','')
}
```

You could also strip the domain prefix from all the user names in one go with the `-replace` operator:

```
foreach($id in $flist.IdentityReference.Value -replace 'Domain\\')
{
    Get-ADGroup $id -Properties member | Select-Object -ExpandProperty member
}
```

Comment: `$ids` is still empty for me
and if i dont `Out-String` i can't replace the Domainname

Comment: Try referencing `$Flist.IdentityReference.Value`, instead of `$Flist.IdentityReference`

Comment: It works this way but i still cant use `-replace` to replace the domainname. I can't immagine noone has a better idea for the code than i >_<

Comment: @seyo-IV I added an example using `-replace` isntead

Answer (score 0):

The Final Script is this, for people who might need something similar. So you can read out the effective permissions and show the group member of permission granted groups.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
$Path   = "\\Server\Share\Logs\"
$Log    = $Path + "Effective_Permissions" + ".log"
$PPath = Read-Host "Enter Path to scan"
$plist = Get-Childitem -Path $PPath -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | Select-Object FullName


foreach($Dir in $PList)
    {
        $Dir = $Dir -replace "@{FullName=", "" -replace "}"
        Resolve-Path -Path $Dir
        Write-Output "`n" | Out-File $log -append
        Write-Output "#######################################################################" | Out-File $Log -append
        Get-Item $Dir | select FullName | Out-File $Log -append
        $AclList = Get-Acl -Path $Dir -Filter Access | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Access | Where-Object {$_.IdentityReference -like "Domain\*"} | Select-Object IdentityReference
        Get-Acl -Path $dir -Filter Access | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Access | Where-Object {$_.IdentityReference -like "Domain\*"} | Out-File $Log -append
            foreach($Id in $AclList.IdentityReference.Value -replace 'Domain\\')
                {
                    $ADGroup = Get-ADGroup $Id -Properties member | Select-Object -ExpandProperty member
                    Write-Output "`n" | Out-File $Log -append
                    Write-Output "Member of $Id `n
---------------------------------" | Out-File $Log -append
                    foreach ($Object in $ADGroup)
                        {
                            $Group      = Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase "$Object"
                            if($Group -ne $null)
                                {
                                    $GrName     = $Group.Name
                                    Write-Output "$GrName" | Out-File $Log -append
                                }
                        } 
                }
Clear-Variable Object, Group, ADGroup, ACLList, GRName, Id
    }
```